# need for an explanation for this bit of code

Tags: javascript

I came across this bit of code that I cannot understand.

```
arr.slice(arr.findIndex(func) >= 0 ? arr.findIndex(func): arr.length, arr.length);
```

I know that the "?" can be thought of as "then" and the ":" as else. I particularly don't understand what this bit `arr.length, arr.length` suppose to mean. If you could explain this to me I'd be thankful

here is the code in full context:

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.slice(arr.findIndex(func) >= 0 ? arr.findIndex(func): arr.length, arr.length);
}
    
// test here
var result = dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {return n >= 3;});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need code explaining, it can be a sign that it's badly written. At the very least a line like that needs a comment explaining it.

Instead, consider rewriting:

```
function dropElements(arr,func) {
    var start = arr.findIndex(func);
    if( start < 0) {
        // no match
        return [];
    }
    else {
        return arr.slice(start);
    }
}
```

Note that the second `arr.length` is redundant - `.slice()` will slice to the end of the array if not otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:

```
if(arr.findIndex(func) >= 0) {
    startI = arr.findIndex(func);
} else {
    startI = arr.length;
}
endI = are.length;
return arr.slice(startI, endI);
```

...does that help?  Basically the ?...: is acting like an if else, then the whole argument is followed by a ..., second argument.  Very confusing, and I hate it when folks don't use parens to clarify order of ops.

Answer (score 0):

If we break up this:
`arr.slice(arr.findIndex(func) >= 0 ? arr.findIndex(func): arr.length, arr.length);` we,ll get: `arr.slice(begin, end)` where

`begin = arr.findIndex(func) >= 0 ? arr.findIndex(func): arr.length`
and
`end = arr.length`

So, this is going to slice from `begin` to the end of the given array

Answer (score 0):

Try brake it down:

```
arr.slice(
    arr.findIndex(func) >= 0 ? arr.findIndex(func) : arr.length, // First argument for slice method
    arr.length  // Second slide argument.
);
```

Now lets try analyse the first argument of the slise:

```
arr.findIndex(func) >= 0 ?   // If the call of arr.findIndex(func) it is greater than 0
arr.findIndex(func) :        // Then return the result of this method call
arr.length                   // Other wise return the length of the arr
```

So what does this code does is, start the array slicing from the number returned from the first ternary operator to the length of the array.